# java double buffering problem

Tags: java

Whats wrong with my applet code which does not render double buffering correctly.I am trying 
and trying.But failed to get a solution.Plz Plz someone tell me whats wrong with my code.

```
import java.applet.* ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.event.* ;


public class Ball extends Applet implements  Runnable
{
    // Initialisierung der Variablen
    int x_pos = 10;     // x - Position des Balles
    int y_pos = 100;    // y - Position des Balles
    int radius = 20;    // Radius des Balles

    Image buffer=null;
    //Graphics graphic=null;

    int w,h;

    public void init()
    {
        Dimension d=getSize();
        w=d.width;
        h=d.height;

        buffer=createImage(w,h);
        //graphic=buffer.getGraphics();

        setBackground (Color.black);

    }

    public void start ()
    {
        // Schaffen eines neuen Threads, in dem das Spiel lไuft
        Thread th = new Thread (this);
        // Starten des Threads
        th.start ();
    }

    public void stop()
    {

    }

    public void destroy()
    {

    }

    public void run ()
    {
        // Erniedrigen der ThreadPriority um zeichnen zu erleichtern
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        // Solange true ist lไuft der Thread weiter
        while (true)
        {
            // Verไndern der x- Koordinate
            repaint();

            x_pos++;
            y_pos++;
            //x2--;
            //y2--;

            // Neuzeichnen des Applets


            if(x_pos>410)
                x_pos=20;

            if(y_pos>410)
                y_pos=20;

            try
            {

                Thread.sleep (30);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                // do nothing
            }

            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {

        Graphics screen=null;

        screen=g;
        g=buffer.getGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.red);


        g.fillOval(x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);


        screen.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);

    }


    public void update(Graphics g)
    {

        paint(g);
    }

}
```

what change should i make.When offscreen image is drawn the previous image also remain in screen.How to erase the previous image from the screen??

Comment: For starters you could stop posting example code with 10 empty methods.

Comment: Hi russel. You have only accepted 33% of 29 questions. Do you really have received unusable answers to 20 of your questions? Please review that and replace the "plz plz plz" in your post by more detailed information about what doesn't work properly. Then you might have better chances to receive answers.

Comment: Ok,i found my problem.I created a new image  buffer=createImage(w,h);
after  ' screen.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);' and then cleanup problem is solved.But now another problem arised ,My moving ball is flickering also.So i m wondered whether or not double-buffering is performed here.how to check this,anyone can help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do not cleanup your buffer image between draws. You could test this by changing your code to:

```
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    screen.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this);

    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
```

Which draws the red ball and wipes it green afterwards, so you sould see a red ball leaving a green trail. Replacing the green color by your background color would do the trick.

Comment: I applied your suggestion,but the problem remain same.Infact
g.setColor(Color.green); this is because of mis-typeing.it should have been comment.the problem is that previous image is remain in the screen/newly written figure is on the previous image,rather than a blank image.how to solve this??

Comment: @russell, my suggestion overwrites the red ball with another color, so next iteration it should not be shown (use green to leave a trail and your background color to hide the ball) your solution creating a new buffer image is equals to overwriting the image with the default color. Could your problem be the result of having a transparent background while clearing it with a non-transparent color?

Comment: I could not understand your ques!!,however thats not a problem.Because at last i became able to remove flickering by setting 
>> screen.drawImage(buffer,0,0,this); to   screen.drawImage(buffer,0,0,null);
thanx you very much for ur help.Hope next time u will also help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearing the buffer between two renderings.

How about adding

```
g.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.getWidth(), buffer.getHeight());
```

using your background color (black?), before calling `g.setColor(Color.RED); g.fillOval...`?

Comment: I used it but problem remain same.still ball  is moving with tail.I dont know what else i can do!!!